# Select css class depend on content

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, vue.js

I have a problem with css.

I would like to select `<tr>` element class. I use bootstrap and I would like to use bootstrap classes like `.success` or `.danger`.

I use vue.js and I have a object with id, name, status, etc., status name doesn't match to .success or .danger but I need to use this two classes depends of status name.

I know two solutions:

1. Write a JS function to return class name depends on status name. `<tr class={{myFun(object.status)}}`. My function is simple case statement.
2. Extend bootstrap class name in sass.
   `.STATUS { @extend .success; }`

I'm beginner with frontend, before I created very simple static html pages and I'm curious which solution I should use? Maybe another one? I tried to find something in internet but I found nothing of interest.
Could anybody have any advice for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Vue's built-in class directive, like so:

```
<tr
  :class="{
    'success': object.status === 'somestatus',
    'error': object.status === 'otherstatus'
  }">
  ...
</tr>
```

There's no need to write a new method for that. Take a look at the [Class & Style Bindings Guide](https://vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax) for more examples.